# I have an abstract class w/ 1 setter method - parameter is an object. I want a generic <T> parameter that takes on the type of the class extending it

Tags: java, class, generics, types, abstract

What I want:

Instead of "Object" in "public void insertDog(Object object)" method, I would like a generic that extends the class extending the abstract class "DogKennel." For example, if I create a class called "RetrieverDogKennel" that extends "DogKennel," I would like the parameter in the "RetrieverDogKennel" class's "insertDog(...)" method to only accept "Retriever" Objects. Though it wouldn't look like this "insertDog(Retriever retriever)" the method would act like it, only allowing retriever objects in its parameter.

```
public abstract class DogKennel
{

   public void insertDog(Object object)
   {

   //does something and the object is not stored

   }

}

public class RetrieverDogKennel extends DogKennel
{

   public <T extends Retriever> void insertDog(T object)
   {

   //does something and the object is not stored

   }

}
```

If you try to put another dog breed into the RetrieverDogKennel, I want it to be an error.

```
LabradorDogKennel labradorDogKennel = new LabradorDogKennel();
RetrieverDogKennel retrieverDogKennel = new LabradorDogKennel();

Labrador bullet = new Labrador(); 
Retriever buster = new Retriever();
Retriever sparky = new Retriever();



//No Error
retrieverDogKennel.insertDog(buster);

//Error
retrieverDogKennel.insertDog(bullet);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You need to make both classes generic, not the subclass method:

```
public interface Dog {
}

public class Labrador implements Dog
{
}

public abstract class DogKennel<T extends Dog> {

    public void insertDog(T dog) {
        //does something and the dog is not stored
    }

}

public final class RetrieverDogKennel extends DogKennel<Retriever> {
}

public final class GeneralDogKennel extends DogKennel<Dog> {
}
```

With that code the `RetrieverDogKennel` class has an `insertDog(Retriever dog)` method, with implementation inherited from the base class.

The `GeneralDogKennel` class has an `insertDog(Dog dog)` method, i.e. it will accept any type of dog.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you for the answer. "public class Retriever<T extends Retriever> extends Dogness<T>" I didn't know you could do that. I tried to upvote you but my reputation won't allow it.

Comment: I made a mistake on my question, but I need the object to be on its own apart from those classes.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Sorry about the confusion. If I am understanding your code correctly, there needs to be a common interface implemented by all the classes, am I correct?

Comment: @KeepAtIt If you don't, then how can the generic `DogKennel` code do anything with the `dog` object, other than e.g. calling `toString()`? If the "does something" logic doesn't care about the object, and it could handle a cat or an airplane, then no, you don't need a `Dog` interface/baseclass.

Comment: The "does something" logic itself is all basic Object logic so it doesn't need anything but the Object itself. However, I want the method "insertDog(...)" on classes that extend the abstract class to not let any other objects in that are not of the type that the class extending the abstract class specifies.

Comment: Using a base empty interface that's implemented by all the objects definitely works and thank you. Can I do it without the interface?

Comment: Oh! I wasn't understanding that you could just use T without extending anything in the abstract class. Great. You solved it!